# WPF Push notifications using PHP

Tags: c#, php, wpf, push-notification

I am developing an wpf application (exe for Windows 7 and above) and in it we need to provide push notifications to the user whenever a new event occurs i.e. any kind of activity is performed on server. I looked for it and all examples were using WCF services but beck-end for my application is in PHP.

So, Is it possible to provide push notifications to wpf app using PHP? How?